# Django unable to translate language

Tags: django, language-translation

I want to translate my website to CH, but no response after I followed the online instruction. Did I miss something?

I have changed the language code in `settings.py`.

**settings.py**:

```
import os
import django_heroku
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
  ('en', ('English')),
  ('zh-Hant', _('Traditional Chinese')),
)
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
...
]
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMP_DIR],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
             ....]}

# LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-Hant'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
]
```

Added the tag for translation in html

**base.html**:

```
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....
```

**home.html**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
{% trans "Let's translate this" %}
....
```

Updated msgstr in ....\locale\zh-Hant\LC_MESSAGESdjango.po:

```
msgid "Let's translate this"
msgstr "來翻譯這個"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Updated msgstr in ....\locale\zh-Hant\LC_MESSAGESdjango.po:

For traditional Chinese:

zh-hant in your config, and your directory should be named `zh_Hant`.

See the locale directory: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth/locale

[**locale name**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#definitions)

A locale name, either a language specification of the form ll or a combined language and country specification of the form ll_CC. Examples: **it, de_AT, es, pt_BR, sr_Latn**. The language part is always in lowercase. The country part is in titlecase if it has more than 2 characters, otherwise it’s in uppercase. The separator is an underscore.

and languages `keys` with lowercase:

```
LANGUAGES = (
  ('en', _('English')),
  ('zh-hant', _('Traditional Chinese')),
)
```

Comment: I do run this command every times after updated in .po files

Comment: @HugoYu, directory should be named `zh_Hant`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Same result even the directory named zh_Hant

Answer (score 0):

Change your language code so that you have `LANGUAGES` like this;

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('ja', gettext('Japanese')),
    ('it', gettext('Italian')),
    ('zh-hant', gettext('Chinese')),
)
```

I've tested this on a multi-lingual site that I have.

```
python manage.py makemessages -l zh-hant
python manage.py compilemessages
```

Django admin then looks like this by default;

[image]

Comment: I have received error: "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty."

Comment: Your settings aren't defined then. You either need to define the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable or pass the `--settings` arg to `runserver`